# Get min and max date from a delta directory using DataBricks

Tags: python, amazon-s3, databricks, delta-lake

I use S3 for my Delta Lake. Basically, my question is:

- **How can I get the min and max date from my delta directories?**

My delta lake is partitioned by date (bsdt) and I have many directories on my base folder, example:

```
s3://deltalake/folder1/subfolder1/deltafolder1/
s3://deltalake/folder2/deltafolder2/
s3://deltalake/folder3/deltafolder3_1/
s3://deltalake/folder3/deltafolder3_2/
s3://deltalake/folder3/subfolder3/deltafolder3_3/
s3://deltalake/folder4/subfolder4/subsubsfolder4/deltafolder4_1/
s3://deltalake/folder4/subfolder4/subsubsfolder4/deltafolder4_2/
```

Each of these folders, on it final path (where _delta_log is located) is partitioned by date (bsdt column).

I tried to develop a recursive function in python using `dbutils.fs.ls()` to get the last folder.

```
def find_path(dir):
    files = dbutils.fs.ls(dir)

    subdirs = [file.path for file in files if file.isDir()]

    if not subdirs:
        return [dir]  # Found final path 

    last_paths = []

    for subdir in subdirs:
        if "_delta_log" in [file.name for file in dbutils.fs.ls(subdir)]:
            last_paths.append(subdir)
        else:
            results = find_path(subdir)
            last_paths.extend(results)

    return last_paths

basedir = "s3://datalake/folder1/"
print(find_path(basedir))
```

The problem with this function is that is taking much time to retrieve only the paths. So, my final question is:

- **What is the easiest way of retrieving the min and max date from my delta directories?**

A desired output is:

```
path                                              min        max
s3://deltalake/folder1/subfolder1/deltafolder1/   2020-01-01 2024-01-22
s3://deltalake/folder2/deltafolder2/              2023-01-01 2024-01-22
```